# Unable to push an update to Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to push an update in the Play Store and I came across the following error. I'm aware of the new target API requirement which will be in effect from November 1st, but as of now, I'm supposed to be able to push an update to play store right? If that's the case, I'm not sure why am I getting this error.

Could some one please help me?

[image: Error]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Google Play Store support and they told me the issue is caused because of the version code number of the app. Though I updated the version, I forgot to update the version code number.

I fixed the version code number and uploaded the APK to the play store and it worked.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's a warning, not an error. It even says "Warning" right there.

You should be able to publish it anyway. The August deadline only applies to new apps.

Comment: It might be a bug in the Play Console then. Regardless, we're only a month away from the hard limit. You should be using 26 by now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This warning does not (or should not) have the capacity to block your release. There are two possibilities:

- your release is being blocked by some other error as well which you aren't noticing because of this warning
- there is a bug in the Play Console

If it is the second option you should report it to the Play Console support team. You can contact them via the help menu in the Play Console, which is behind the "?" (Question Mark) icon. But the first option is more likely.